# How to extract all matches from a string using single regular expression in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, substring

I want to insert all matched patterns into a single array using a regular expression in PHP.

For example, I have following text:

> calculated F 1a5 5W13 153w135 1E55 12_5 1.56 1M55

My php code is like this:

```
$txt="calculated 1a5 5W13 153w135 1E55 12_5 1.56 1M55";
preg_match_all("/calculated F( ([\d\w_\.]+))+/s",$txt,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

I need somethings like as:

```
Array ( [0] =>1a5, [1]=> 5W13, [2]=>  153w135, [3]=>  1E55, [4]=>  12_5, [5]=>  1.56, [6]=> 1M55)
```

Comment: How can I do in Javascript or Jquery? Can the regex code valid in http://regexr.com ?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/G6mIVp/2 could be the better explanation.

Comment: @sln your answer is very practical and useful to me. But using a regular expression is the best method in PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the following regex solution:

```
$txt="calculated F 15 513 153135 155 125 156 155";
preg_match_all("/(?:\G(?!\A)|calculated(?:\s+F)?)\s*\K[\w.]+/",$txt,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Afj68Q/3).

Also, see the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/LWbJAa).

Note that it is basically your regex with a custom `\G` based boundary added to match consecutive matches after a specific pattern added. Note that your `[\d\w_\.]` is the same as `[\w.]` as `\w` matches what `\d` and `_` match.

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|calculated(?:\s+F)?)` - either the end of the previous match (`\G(?!\A)`, `\G` by itself matches start of a string or the end of the previous match, thus, `(?!\A)` subtracts the start of string position) or `calculated` + 1 or - optionally - more whitespaces + `F` (matched with the `calculated(?:\s+F)?` branch)
- `\s*` -  zero or more whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `[\w.]+` - 1 or more digits, letters, `_` or `.` characters.

Comment: I need it for some complex version of it. I edited the question, could you mind to revisit it?

Comment: @Huseyin:  I see that you updated a question, but only changed the example string and example output. You did not provide exact requirements. I do not know now what you need. You made your question unclear. Now, I can only guess that you want to match any sequence of 1+ non-whitespaces after a specific string. Try [replacing last `\d+` with `\S+` and make `\s+F` optional](https://regex101.com/r/Afj68Q/2). My solution is still viable for your new scenario.

Comment: I updated the answer using your own logic in the pattern. Really hope that will help.

Comment: WOW. Great solution. Could you help me to select only LA701 LIPIJAP LIPIKOR LREX   in https://regex101.com/r/G6mIVp/3

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I want obtain array ("LA701" , "LIPIJAP", "LIPIKOR", "LREX") from https://regex101.com/r/G6mIVp/3

Comment: @Huseyin: See [`(?:Variables are:|\G(?!\A))\h+\K\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/G6mIVp/4).

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way is to match the values en masse then just split() on whitespace.

Code sample

```
$txt="calculated F 15 513 153135 155 125 156 155  ";
if ( preg_match('~calculated F \s*(\d+(?:\s*\d+)*)~', $txt, $matches) )
    print_r( preg_split( '~\s+~', $matches[1] ) );
```

https://ideone.com/pbCWgU

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 513
    [2] => 153135
    [3] => 155
    [4] => 125
    [5] => 156
    [6] => 155
)
```

Comment: This is a very brilliant solution, but I need it based on regex without a split.

Answer (score 1):

Updated my answer after OP updated question details...

If you know `calculated` is going to be at the front of the string and the rest is a space delimited set of valid values, then I advise against using regex because it is slower / less efficient.

This is all you need:

```
$txt="calculated 1a5 5W13 153w135 1E55 12_5 1.56 1M55";
var_export(array_slice(explode(' ',$txt),1));
```

This will explode the string on spaces, and remove the leading element from the exploded result array.

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '1a5',
  1 => '5W13',
  2 => '153w135',
  3 => '1E55',
  4 => '12_5',
  5 => '1.56',
  6 => '1M55',
)
```

If your input string might have `F` after `calculated`, please update your question -- because this is inconsistent in your question and this is vital information.

Regex is overkill when string/array manipulations provide the same level of accuracy with greater efficiency.

The only logical reason to use regex in your case is if `calculated` may be optionally trailed by an unwanted non-white-space character like `F`.  In which case you can use this simple/effective pattern:

```
$txt="calculated F 1a5 5W13 153w135 1E55 12_5 1.56 1M55";
var_export(preg_match_all('/\K\d\S*/',$txt,$out)?$out[0]:'no match');
// output same as previous method
```

This method will make fullstring matches starting from each number until it reaches a white-space character.

Comment: @Huseyin I just happen to revisit this page because it was left open on my other computer.  I see that you have updated your input data.  I have provided two simple/accurate/optimized methods considering your new input data that outperform the others.